# Leaflet, wrong API key when using CloudMade tiles!

Tags: leaflet, cloudmade

I've registered on CloudMade and got some API keys but non of them work with Leaflet API. When I checked for image URLs and opened each directly using my browser it prints out the message "Wrong apikey". Anyone with the same issue?

Comment: Also make sure you have clicked the confirmation email from CloudMade when creating an account

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem, then I decided to inspect [leftletjs.com](http://leafletjs.com/) maps, and realized the api key must be uppercase.